# Can a new app signed against new keystore be uploaded if my app was previously in draft state?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I was trying to upload an android app on google play console. I had google play console app signing checked. I uploaded a random apk generated using random keystore and the app was in draft state. Now app signing contains app signing certificate and upload certificate. Now I want to upload actual apk signed against genuine keystore certificate but i get error that signing certificate mismatches.

At no point, my app was rolled out, it was in draft state all the time. Is it possible to upload a new apk signed using new keystore? Or make app signing forget old certificates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it yourself. But if you contact Google Play support they should be able to delete the APK for you if you have never published it. You can contact them using the help menu on the Play Console, which is behind the "?" icon.

Comment: Hi, thank you Nick. If I create a new draft and upload with new key, do you foresee an issue with same application is being used?

Comment: Play console support are best to answer that